# Can't access laravel response from ajax library

Tags: ajax, laravel

// Edit: Hm...this is an firebug bug in firefox. On chrome it works...

I'm using Laravel 5.3 with Vue 2.0 and the axios ajax library.

Here is a test controller, where i return a `response` from laravel:

```
public function testMethod() {
  return response('this is an error', 500);
}
```

Here is my ajax call:

```
 http(`fetch-data`).then(response => {
   const data = response.data;

   console.log(data);
 }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error); // <- This doens't work, he show my nothing
    alert(error);
 });
```

The problem is, i need the error message which is returned from laravel into my client `catch`. But if i `console.log` them, he show me nothing. If i `alert` the error, he gives me the following message: `Error: Request failed with status code 500`.

Why can't i access something like `error.statusCode`, `error.statusMessage`?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
return response()->json('this is an error', 500);
```